# Mapbox.js not working with Internet Explorer for local files

Tags: internet-explorer, leaflet, mapbox

I have a local html file for a simple map. I use the latest version of mapbox.js to get the tiles and when I open it in Firefox everything is fine. But opening it in Internet Explorer 10 results in blank webpage with only the zoom controls in the upper left corner and shows the "SCRIPT5: Access is denied" message in the console. After switching to leaflet.js the map shows up without any problems on IE10.

I need to show the local file in an application which only has IE10 engine as rendering backend, so not using IE10 or hosting the webpage online is not an option.

As mapbox.js is a leaflet.js plug-in, I'm wondering where the difference comes from and if any fix for this issue is available.

Cheers,
Daniel